# Вычислить время выполнения алгоритма и записать результат используя асимптотическую нотацию

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, асимптотика

Рассчитайте время выполнения алгоритма (псевдокод приведен ниже). Запишите результат асимптотической нотацией. Объясните каждый шаг [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вы только начните, а мы подмогнем!

Answer (score 2):

Если все работает строго как написано, без оптимизаций, то мы получаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Согласно основной теореме (см. *Кормен и др., Алгоритмы, построение и анализ, 3 изд.*, стр. 120), поскольку a = 4, b = 2 и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и всё.